# OnEdit Script that will only read data from Specific cells range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which I have been given by a fellow Google Sheets Helper.

I would like to change the script to activate only from CELL 4 to 34 ONLY in column E
What would i need to change in the current script to achieve this?

Please see example sheet link below and also the script

LINK
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15XQg9ojPeQorKDenL0HmU0QQNZwN8_ABHSn2Abw9o84/edit?usp=sharing

SCRIPT

```
/**
* Make corrections to source sheet from the target sheet
* To allow users to make corrections without risk of editing the incorrect column in the source sheet
* Author: Mr Shane
* Version: 2023-04-11-01
⇨ For: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/210353550
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/

function onEdit(e) {
if(!e) throw Error ("Do not run this script from the Apps Script Editor. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.");
onEditFunction_(e);
}

function onEditFunction_(e) {
const TABSEX = ["Daily Pay","Instructions"]; // Sheets to EXCLUDE from monitoring for an event/edit.
const MONITORCOL = 5; // Configure the column that will be monitored.
const r = e.range; // Cell being edited.
const value = e.value; // The value of the edited cell
const row = r.rowStart; // Row of the edit.
const editedCol = r.columnStart; // Column of the edit.
const sh = r.getSheet(); // Sheet on which the edit was done.
const sheetName = sh.getName(); // Name of the sheet on which the edit was done.
const shExcluded = TABSEX.includes(sheetName); // TRUE if sheetName is included.

if( editedCol !== MONITORCOL || shExcluded === true ) return; // Abort if edit is (a) not in monitored column, or (b) on a sheet that is excluded from monitoring
const ss = e.source;
const sheetNumber = parseInt(sheetName.match(/\d+/)[0]); // Extract the number from the sheetName, and parseInt.
ss.getSheetByName("Daily Pay").getRange(row+0,sheetNumber+1).setValue(value); // Write the value to the applicable cell (with row & column offset correction).
r.clear();
}

/** END onEdit Script */
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I would like to change the script to activate only from CELL 4 to 34 ONLY in column E`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

So you did monitor only column number 5.
If initialized at 1, is column E
And I added a condition in the row number, to be between 4 and 34.

```js
/**
* Make corrections to source sheet from the target sheet
* To allow users to make corrections without risk of editing the incorrect column in the source sheet
* Author: Mr Shane
* Version: 2023-04-11-01
⇨ For: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/210353550
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/

function onEdit(e) {
if(!e) throw Error ("Do not run this script from the Apps Script Editor. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.");
onEditFunction_(e);
}

function onEditFunction_(e) {
const TABSEX = ["Daily Pay","Instructions"]; // Sheets to EXCLUDE from monitoring for an event/edit.
const MONITORCOL = 5; // Configure the column that will be monitored.
const r = e.range; // Cell being edited.
const value = e.value; // The value of the edited cell
const row = r.rowStart; // Row of the edit.
const editedCol = r.columnStart; // Column of the edit.
const sh = r.getSheet(); // Sheet on which the edit was done.
const sheetName = sh.getName(); // Name of the sheet on which the edit was done.
const shExcluded = TABSEX.includes(sheetName); // TRUE if sheetName is included.

if( editedCol !== MONITORCOL || shExcluded === true || row<4 || row>34) return; // Abort if edit is (a) not in monitored column, or (b) on a sheet that is excluded from monitoring
const ss = e.source;
const sheetNumber = parseInt(sheetName.match(/\d+/)[0]); // Extract the number from the sheetName, and parseInt.
ss.getSheetByName("Daily Pay").getRange(row+0,sheetNumber+1).setValue(value); // Write the value to the applicable cell (with row & column offset correction).
r.clear();
}

/** END onEdit Script */
```

Comment: Hi Benoit Drogou,

Thank you for the change in my code this works perfect.

Could i ask you for a bit more help.

would there be any way to make the code so that when I enter any data in Column E on 01/00/00 which would autofill Column B in "DATA ENTRY" then column B to autofill column C,D,E etc in that row, but with the function for me to still be able to change data in any of the column/cells when data entered in sheets 01/00/00 to 31/00/00

Regrads

Ylli